# Why ignore is no use after set style is null?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a MenuItem, and items always use same style, the only one item use difference style.

So, I set two style to same target type. Just see my xaml code:

```
<Menu>
  <Menu.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
          <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding ActionCommand}"/>
          <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Header}"/>
      </Style>
      <!--Hierarchical MenuItmes-->
      <Style x:Key="MenuItemsCommand" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
          <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}" />
      </Style>
      <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="ItemsTemplate"
                        DataType="{x:Type vm:MenuItemsViewModel}" 
                        ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}">
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"/>
      </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
  </Menu.Resources>
  <MenuItem Header="Files">
      <MenuItem Header="{Binding Open}" InputGestureText="Ctrl+O"/>

      <!--ignore default style-->
      <MenuItem Header="Open Recent file"
            Style="{x:Null}"  
            ItemsSource="{Binding RecentFiles}"
            ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MenuItemsCommand}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemsTemplate}">
      </MenuItem>

      <MenuItem Header="_Save" CommandParameter="{Binding Save}" InputGestureText="Ctrl+S"/>
  </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

The MenuItems always binding `ActionCommand`. But someone is binding Command.

So I want to ignore original style, set `Style="{x:Null}"`. But I got binding error when I open this MeunItems.

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'ActionCommand' property not found on 'object' ''OpenFileList' (HashCode=27335113)'. BindingExpression:Path=ActionCommand; DataItem='OpenFileList' (HashCode=27335113); target element is 'MenuItem' (Name=''); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')
```

The ignore is work? I have no idea to do something.

Comment: `<Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding ActionCommand}"/>` -- this binds to MenuItem, not it's datacontext. Obviously MenuItem control has no property of yours. Try `<Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding DataContext.ActionCommand}"/>`

Comment: You can try to set OverridesDefaultStyle to true.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.overridesdefaultstyle(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Not this problem. I set datacontext in code-behind, and it work. They are work, but just show binding error.

Comment: I try `OverridesDefaultStyle` and got more trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using an implicit `Style` at all here? Can't you just set the `Style` property of the `Open` and `Save` items to the style that binds to the `Command` property?:

```
<Menu>
    <Menu.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="style1" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding ActionCommand}"/>
            <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Header}"/>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="MenuItemsCommand" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}" />
        </Style>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="ItemsTemplate"
                        DataType="{x:Type vm:MenuItemsViewModel}" 
                        ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </Menu.Resources>
    <MenuItem Header="Files">
        <MenuItem Header="{Binding Open}" InputGestureText="Ctrl+O" Style="{StaticResource style1}"/>

        <!--ignore default style-->
        <MenuItem Header="Open Recent file"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding RecentFiles}"
                    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MenuItemsCommand}"
                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemsTemplate}">
        </MenuItem>

        <MenuItem Header="_Save" CommandParameter="{Binding Save}" InputGestureText="Ctrl+S" Style="{StaticResource style1}"/>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Or do you simply want to set the `Command` property of the "Open Recent file" to `null`?:

```
<MenuItem Header="Open Recent file"
          Command="{x:Null}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding RecentFiles}"
          ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MenuItemsCommand}"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemsTemplate}">
```

You should always create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your issue when asking a question. The XAML markup is not enough to reproduce your issue in this case.

Comment: Thx for you. Because I have not only two items to use this `style1`, but only one item use `MenuItemsCommand` style. However, I try to set `Command={x:Null}`, but it's same binding error.

Comment: But my issue just those of xaml, and this xaml is extracted after I trace bug.